# Source for useful EC2 AMIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

Using Amazon's own [client libraries](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=552&categoryID=187) (or [alternatives](http://code.google.com/p/typica/)), you can get listings of available pre-packaged AMIs, but the interface is definitely designed for scriptability, not readability. [Elasticfox](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=609) is better, but still doesn't make it easy to see what an AMI *does*, allow for user rating, etc.

Is there a centralised place for me to easily find AMIs for specific purposes? AMIs for Apache, OpenMQ, MySQL, that sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [list](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/kbcategory.jspa?categoryID=101) of shared AMIs. I am afraid that you can't automatically search the list by a keyword in the title or the description.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [this list](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/kbcategory.jspa?categoryID=101&resultOffset=0&sortField=9&sortOrder=0&filterEntryTypeID=-1)? It's just as cluttered as the elasticfox listing, but includes descriptions.

Sounds like someone should screen scrape this page and make it searchable..